# Как в Django сгруппировать объекты в шаблоне

Tags: python, django

Условно имеется модель:

```
сlass Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenth=64)
    group = models.CharField(max_lenth=64)
```

и объекты этой модели:

```
[{'name': Person_1, 'group': Group_1}, {'name': Person_2, 'group': Group_1}, {'name': Person_3, 'group': Group_2}, {'name': Person_4, 'group': Group_2}]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы объекты с одинаковым полем 'group' сгруппировались в шаблоне? Цель всего этого получить примерно следующее: из вьюхи подгружаются все объекты модели, группируются, при нажатии на группу открывается выпадающий список со всеми объектами, имеющими одинаковое поле 'group'.

```
Group_1:
   -Person_1 
   -Person_2
Group_2:
    -Person_3
    -Person_4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Специально для этой цели есть [тег regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup):

```
{% regroup persons by group as groups %}

<ul>
{% for group in groups %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for person in group.list %}
          <li>{{ person.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант при получении QuerySet преобразовывать его в dict.
А затем отсортировать его, вот тут подробный [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751979/grouping-python-dictionary-keys-as-a-list-and-create-a-new-dictionary-with-this).